# What is the permutation matrix associated to the permutation of $n$ indices?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the permutation matrix associated to the permutation of $n$ indices defined by
$p(i) = n - i + 1$? What is the cycle decomposition of $p$ ? What is its sign ?

Pliz help me. I'm  newly learning abstract algebra and pliz don't vote down..
Any hints/solution.
Thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $n=4$ then 
$$p(1)=4-1+1=4$$
$$p(2)=4-2+1=3$$
$$p(3)=4-3+1=2$$
and $p(4)=1$

So as you can see this permutation has the following cycle decomposition 
$$(14)(23).$$
This will be general pattern for $n$ even you would have 
$$(1,n)(2,n-1)(3,n-2)...(n/2,n/2+1)$$
Can you try to get the cycle for $n$ odd?

Comment: Thanks u so much @hello _world